# Scraping hyperlinks from a table using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have this table with two columns and unknown number of rows. I am trying to use Selenium (with Python) to scrape all the links into a list.

[image]

Goal: get all the links (one per row) from the second column into a list.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('') #for the table
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)

\#Output is:
Penn Affiliated:
Delaware Valley Regional Planning Commission Congestion Management Intern
Contracts Intern
Transit, Bike, and Pedestrian Planning
Fabrication Lab Laser Cutter Operator
...
```

This prints all the rows. Now I am unsure of how to get links from the second column and all the rows.

Here is the HTML for the table:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Share relevant HTML

Comment: @ShivamMishra added to the post.

Comment: @VrajShroff Update the question with text based _HTML_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of `href` attribute from your element, you can do this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class = 'search']//td/a") 
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't give a URL, but basically it should be like this.

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.parse('http://www.gpsbasecamp.com/national-parks')
links = doc.xpath('//a[@href]')
for link in links:
    print(link.attrib['href'])
```